# Image deterioration in android app, using Galaxy Tab 10.1

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

I tested my app on Galaxy tab 10.1 and found something strange.

I use a large image as title of app created for large screen. But when checked it, image quality is lowered.

I never touched image like resizing. Image resolution is fit so there is nothing to change.

When viewing same image on gallary, it seems almost same.
Only in app, image is deteriorated.

I using image folder drawble-xhdpi and layout folder layout-xlarge.
Is there something more i should check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check what density the device you're testing on actually is. The Galaxy Tab 10.1 is an `mdpi` device, not an `xhdpi` device. Also, it's recommended *not* to use the `large` and `xlarge` qualifiers, and instead to use the smallest-width qualifiers (e.g. `sw600dp` for 7", `sw720dp` for 10").